# For condition not showing up in grafana for alerting

Tags: alert, grafana

Any one please help if we need to enable any config for showing up for condition in Grafana.

In my grafana system which is it old (4.6) , for option is not showing up for alerting.

I am not sure if any config needs to be enabled for it or this is not supported in 4.6 or older verion.[image: Missing for option]

Answer (score 0):

For is available after Grafana 5.4 https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v6.0/alerting/rules/

[image: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v6.0/alerting/rules/]